# Can I dock UIToolbar on UIPickerview like docked on Keyboard

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I have created a custom uitoolbar, containing buttons B1,B2 and textview.

Toolbar scrolls up and down as per keyboard movement on screen. [Docked on keyboard using]:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView
{
    return _inputbar;
}
```

Toolbar before editing textview & Toolbar scrolled up when begin editing.

[image: toolbar before editing textview]
[image: Toolbar scrolled up when begin editing]

Now i want to use UIPickerView as input for textview in toolbar, which i want to scroll from bottom along with toolbar.

UIPickerView will appear on Clicking B1 button on left side of TextView.
After clicking B1, UIPickerView should scroll up with toolbar on top of picker view.

Is it possible same way as toolbar scrolls up with the keyboard?
Or other proper way??

Answer (score 0):

In the textView use

```
 myT.inputView = pickerView
 pickerView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

for the case you want the textView to show a pickerView i.e. when you click `B1`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @hassan i know to set picker view as inputView for textView, I am trying bring toolbar and pickerview up [toolbar docked above pickerview] when click on B1.